# How do decorators mark a function?

Tags: python, flask, decorator, python-decorators

I was going throught the basic Flask tutorial which has the following code:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Also I went through the basics of Python decorators from many websites including [Stackoverflow Decorators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739654/how-can-i-make-a-chain-of-function-decorators-in-python)

I was of the assumption that in the previous code, the function `hello` will be changed and decorated, and for running the application I need to call the function `hello()` somewhere. How does Flask determine the name of the function it has to call.

Does just wrapping the function definition with a decorator somehow marks that function? If so, how?

For example in the below code, somewhere down the line I'm calling the function I've decorated:

```
def decorate(foo):
    print("I'm doing a lot of important stuff right now")

    def inner():
        print("Some stuff 1")
        foo()
        print("Some stuff 2")

    return inner

@decorate
def hello():
    print("Hello")

hello()
```

Comment: This link might help: http://ains.co/blog/things-which-arent-magic-flask-part-1.html

Comment: If you went through the basics then you should know we can still access it using the name `hello` because the above thing is equivalent to: `hello = @app.route("/")(hello)`.

Comment: But for that to happen I'll need to call `hello()`, which I'm not doing in Flask code

Comment: @KartikAnand You don't have to because flask does that for you when the route `'/'` is accessed. Similarly in the second example when you call `hello()` you're actually calling `inner()` which in turn calls the actual `hello()`.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary I understand the part wherein calling `hello()` calls the `inner()` and in turn calls the original `hello()`. What I don't understand is how does Flask access the original `hello()` inside `/`.

Comment: @KartikAnand It stores them in a dictionary using the url endpoint: https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/blob/master/flask/app.py#L65

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `decorate`, `foo` is the function you are decorating (in this case, `hello`). You can store the function in a list or dictionary somewhere, since it's a normal object.

For example:

```
decorated_functions = []

def decorate(foo):
    def inner():
        print("Some stuff 1")
        foo()
        print("Some stuff 2")

    decorated_functions.append(inner)
    return inner

@decorate
def hello():
    print("Hello")

## The above is the same as:
# def hello():
#     print("Hello")
# hello = decorate(hello)

print(decorated_functions[0] == hello) # prints True
decorated_functions[0]() # prints "Some stuff 1", "Hello", and "Some stuff 2"
hello() # same as above
```

Comment: How does the `print` statement in your code work? I haven't called any function, so how does the list get populated?

Comment: @KartikAnand You've called the `decorate` function; see the edit.

Comment: So the moment I decorate a function, it calls it and thus I can save it in a list!

Answer (score 1):

Decorators are actually a very simple construct in Python.  The following two examples are equivalent:

```
@foo
def bar():
     pass
```

```
def bar():
     pass

bar = foo(bar)
```

So your definition of `hello` in your first example is the equivalent to this:

```
def hello():
     return "Hello World!"

hello = app.route("/")(hello)
```

The double function calls might be a bit confusing so lets rewrite it like this:

```
_tempfn = app.route("/")
hello = _tempfn(hello)
```

So it should be clear now that `app.route` isn't actually a decorator, it's a function that *creates* decorators.  Now what isn't obvious is what the newly decorator does. Without looking at the source for Flash, it's likely that it adds the function `hello` to a dictionary member of a `app`.  So `app.route` is implemented something like this:

```
class app(object):
    def route(self, path):
        def decorator(fn):
            self.pathmap[path] = fn
            return fn
        return decorator
```

Note that this is pretty much a condensed version of the explanation given in the link that [Jon Piparsky provided](http://ains.co/blog/things-which-arent-magic-flask-part-1.html).

Answer (score 1):

The decorator is simply registering the function in a lookup table. Decorators don't need to modify a function in any way, there are so many other useful things, decorators can do.

In fact, decorators in python

```
@some_decorator
def foo():
    pass
```

are only a short form of

```
def foo():
    pass

foo = some_decorator(foo)
```

and the function `some_decorator` can do anything with its arguments and can return any return value, but usually returns a function.